# Assign static id to usb printer

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I have three usb receipt printers from the same vendor (thus the same usb vendor and product id) plugged into the same server and I need to be able to issue separate printing commands to each of them. The printers register themselves to /dev/usb/lp* so I can just write ESC/POS commands into those files and the printers print the appropriate receipts. The issue however is that upon reboot sometimes the order changes, for instance /dev/usb/lp0 now refers to the printer that was /dev/usb/lp1 before. Is there a way to assign a per-device id or at least per usb port id so that it will always refer to the same printer?

Comment: What OS you are on ? I guess linux as you state /dev/ device, but it would be nice to know the OS/version

Comment: @yagmoth555 Ubuntu, kernel version 4.18.0-15-generic

Comment: for the future you might want to add the exact ubuntu version as well, not just "ubuntu", there are ~40 or so versions, though the kernel info limits the possibility quite much.

Comment: 18.10, but it doesn't matter in this case

Answer (score 2):

I found an ugly solution, if you have a more elegant solution please post your answer.

I wrote a script that uses a regex to parse the output of `dmesg | grep usblp | grep 0x0416` (0x0416 is the vendor id for my usb printers).

The output looks as follows:

```
[    9.875206] usblp 2-2:1.0: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 2 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x0416 pid 0x5011
[    9.879408] usblp 3-1:1.0: usblp1: USB Bidirectional printer dev 2 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x0416 pid 0x5011
[    9.883841] usblp 3-2:1.0: usblp2: USB Bidirectional printer dev 3 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x0416 pid 0x5011
```

I use a simple regex: `/usblp ([0-9]\-[0-9])\:1\.0\: usblp([0-9])/` to isolate the usb port (2-2, 3-1 or 3-2) with it's corresponding usblp id, then I just have an hashmap that maps each usb port into a friendly name.

It's ugly, it requires parsing dmesg, but it seems to work so far.

Comment: do the printer have serial numbers you can read out via usb? there was(is?) a tool named usb-devices and a virtual file in /proc/ somewhere which should be able to do that.
additionally lsusb -v might already help you at least get you better info

additionally udev should be able to distinquish between the physical port you attach.
so a udev rule which defines the name based on the port should in theory work.

Comment: usb-devices doesn't seem to report any information related to this

Answer (score 0):

Create a symlink  I did it on one of my machines in Ubuntu 22.04 5.19.0-32-generic and I was able to echo to the symlink to print.

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
## checks for symlink and removes it if needed
if [ -L /dev/usb/lp0 ]; then
               rm /dev/usb/lp0
fi
# create symlink if it is /dev/usb/lp0 is not present to link printer to /dev/usb/lp0
if ! [ -f /dev/usb/lp0 ]; then
        prport=$(ls -l /dev/usb/lp* |awk '{print $10}')
        ln -s $prport /dev/usb/lp0
fi
```